# Cannot select a system image in AVD Manager

Tags: android-studio

This is my screenshoot for Next Button not turn on when i am trying to create Virtual Device in AVD Manager but system image cannot be selected and next button not turn on.

I am running Android Studio using 32bit computer with 1GB RAM and everything is okay, except its AVD Manager cannot be selected system image. Do you know what should i do, so the Next Button on this image below can turn on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be having at least 4gb RAM.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i was in poor, but 2 months ago I already have good laptop.

Comment: My system has 6GB RAM but facing the same issue

Comment: my system has 128GB RAM BUT STILL has the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem - expand the column where the names of the images are - then, all of the sudden the "download" link appears.
Go through the download process and accept the license if you have to.
and it should work from there.
Stupid idiotic problem to have, found the solution by accident.